# WindowsでMicrosoftアカウントを利用しないデメリット

Tags: windows

Microsoftアカウントを使わずにPCを利用するデメリットは何が考えられますか？ 今の状態からMSアカウントを設定することは出来ますができるだけシンプルに使いたいという思いもありこのままで行こうかなとも思っています。

Windows 11のPCでMSアカウントを利用しないことによるデメリットはどんな事が考えられますか？主な利用用途はエディタのVSCode、XamppやDockerを使ったPHPの学習、あとはGitやNode.jsなどです。

何か思い当たる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 微妙にオフトピックぽい(回答があっても質問者さんがそれを問題だとしなければ関係無い)ので、Windows10向け(Windows11でも類似しているでしょう)のこれらの記事から自分で判断してみてください。[Windows 10 Microsoft アカウントとローカルアカウントの違い](https://www.tipsfound.com/windows10/02001), [Windows 10 Microsoftアカウントとローカルアカウントの違い](https://tanweb.net/2015/12/18/5757/), [Windows 10のMicrosoftアカウントとローカルアカウントの違い](https://www.4900.co.jp/smarticle/11223/), [Windows 10、Microsoftアカウントとローカルアカウントはどう違う？](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/20210129-1677890/)

Comment: sayuriさん回答のWindows11ほど直接的では無いですが、Windows10でもMicrosoftアカウント関連で類似なことが書かれていますね。[Windows 10 コンピュータの仕様とシステム要件を見つける方法](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/windows-10-specifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows 11のシステム要件](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/windows-11-specifications)に

> Windows 11 Home エディションにはインターネット接続と Microsoft アカウントが必要です。
> Windows 11 Home の S モードを解除する場合もインターネット接続が必要です。S モードの詳細はこちら。
> すべての Windows 11 エディションで、更新の実行、ダウンロード、一部の機能を使用するために、インターネットのアクセスが必要となります。一部の機能を利用するにはMicrosoft アカウント が必要です。

と明記され、特にHomeエディションではMicrosoftアカウントが必要となりました。EULAはまだ公開されていませんが、記述内容によってはMicrosoftアカウントを利用しないことはライセンス違反につながる可能性もあります。（杞憂かもしれませんが）

---

まぁ、質問は「一部の機能を利用するにはMicrosoft アカウント が必要です。」の部分の詳細を尋ねるものかもしれませんが…。

Answer (score 1):

デメリットは特にないと思いますが、出来ないことはあります。
Windows Insider Programなどはログインしないと利用できなかったと思います。

Answer (score 0):

一番のデメリットは、自作PC等のリテール版OSを使う場合に限ってですが、ハードウェア変更時等にプロダクトキーの再認証やライセンス移行が出来ないことです。Windowsではハードウェア不良やアクシデントで突然ライセンス再認証が要求される場合がありますが、デバイスがMicrosoftアカウントに登録してあると（通常は）容易に再認証可能です。

参考までに補足するとMicrosoftアカウントはハードウェア変更時のライセンス再認証の命綱的な役割を持ちますが、経験上デバイス登録や再認証が正しく動作しない場合もあり、使いこなしには注意が必要です。